# How to use Node.js without .js files, callbacks, promises, etc?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run node without .js files to debug some automation I want to do with chrome headless (puppeteer).

**I want to type 1 command, then see the result, then type another one, etc.** Here's the problem I come into:

```
node --require puppeteer 

> var puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
> var browser = puppeteer.launch({headless: false, waitUntil: 'networkidle'})
```

So far so good, browser opens.

```
> var page = browser.newPage()
```

Then I get this error `TypeError: browser.newPage is not a function`

Now I know that `puppeteer.launch()` returns a promise, which is why it's not working. But how can I use it without writing a promise chain in a .js file? I want to type one command, see the result, type another one, etc. **I don't want to have to reopen the browser every time.**

Comment: Does obeying syntax rules and completing your statements with a semicolon (`;`) help?

Comment: @paulsm4 it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
node --require puppeteer

> var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
> var browser = null;
> puppeteer.launch({headless: false, waitUntil: 'networkidle'})
    .then(tempBrowser => browser = tempBrowser);
> var page = browser.newPage();

...
```

Comment: hi, I'm using puppeteer 1.3.0 and I've tried your example and when I try to do page.goto(URL) I get  "TypeError: page.goto is not a function
", any idea why?